# How to access inputted string in onReleaseKey

Tags: android, keyboard

I wish to implement my own keyboard like the following

https://github.com/rkkr/simple-keyboard

The change that I want to implement is that text should non-capital vowels into one capital vowel. E.g.- saarc -> sArc. So when the user presses the `a` again I want to modify the input to replace the `aa` to A.

In `KeyboardState.java`, I found the following piece of code

`public void onReleaseKey(final int code, final boolean withSliding, final int autoCapsFlags, final int recapitalizeMode)`

However, I am not sure how to access the inputted text so that I can modify it.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open the `KeyboardState.java` file in your project.
2. Inside the `onReleaseKey` method, you can input text using `mBuffer.toString()`.

```
import com.example.simplekeyboard.SimpleKeyboard;

public class KeyboardState {
   private SimpleKeyboard mKeyboard;
   private StringBuilder mBuffer = new StringBuilder();

   public KeyboardState(SimpleKeyboard keyboard) {
       mKeyboard = keyboard;
   }

   public void onReleaseKey(final int code, final boolean withSliding, final int autoCapsFlags, final int recapitalizeMode) {
       // Access the entered text as a string
       String inputText = mBuffer.toString();

       // Apply the transformation of lowercase vowels into a single uppercase vowel
       String transformedText = transformText(inputText);

       // Display the transformed text on the keyboard
       mKeyboard.setKeyboardText(transformedText);

       // Reset the keyboard buffer
       mBuffer.setLength(0);
   }

   private String transformText(String inputText) {
       // Replace lowercase vowels with a single uppercase vowel
       inputText = inputText.replaceAll("a", "A");
       inputText = inputText.replaceAll("e", "E");
       inputText = inputText.replaceAll("i", "I");
       inputText = inputText.replaceAll("o", "O");
       inputText = inputText.replaceAll("u", "U");

       return inputText;
   }

   // Other methods and code in the KeyboardState class as needed
}
```

Comment: `import com.example.simplekeyboard.SimpleKeyboard;` Where can this be found?

Comment: Is this code applicable here?